# Command line error while building jenetics library

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-errors, jenetics

I'm attempting to build the Java jenetics library for genetic algorithms as per [this website](http://jenetics.io/).

However, as can be seen in the image below I'm having some issues that I'm not able to resolve.

[image]

Am I missing something from the instructions or have I done something else weird?

Furthermore, I want to be able to use this library via Eclipse, so any hints as to how to achieve that would also be welcome, just in case what seems like a straight forward explanation on the website should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line show a doubled `C:\PROGRA~1\jenetics-3.6.0` string at the beginning. But even without this error, the given line is not the appropriate build command. 
Jenetics uses Gradle as build system. Calling Gradle wrapper script `.\gradlew jar` should build the jar file(s).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Worked beautifully.